# Knowledge base/wiki system

Tags: gratis, open-source, php, wiki, knowledge-base

Im looking for a knowledge base/wiki/FAQ system that fits these criteria:

- Free
- Written in PHP
- Rich text editing (rather than markdown)
- Has search functionality
- Categories
- In general, user friendly, easy for non technical people to use

Comment: Why written in PHP specifically?

Comment: @user258365 mostly so I could integrate it easily into other systems, but I guess I would be open to other platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Synology NAS provides add-on packages. One of them looks like it would be appropriate for your needs.

[**DokuWiki**](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#) is free and runs on multiple OS. It seems to tick all of your requirements.  As far as being user friendly and easy, that’s subjective. You’ll need to decide by downloading and testing it.

DokuWiki is designed with a plug-in architecture.  Available plugins include [CKGEdit](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:ckgedit) which is based on [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).